# Changing font-family font-size and font-weight with javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the following javascript to change the content of the textareas depending on what is selected in the dropdown boxes.
http://jsfiddle.net/73udajhm/

The Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#fontsize").on('change', function () {
    $('.address').css('font-size', $(this).val() + 'px');
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#fonttype").on('change', function () {
    $('.address').css('font-family', $(this).val());
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#fontweight").on('change', function () {
    $('.address').css('font-weight', $(this).val());
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
Font Size:
<select id="fontsize">
<option>-</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
</select>

<br />Font Type:
<select name="fonttype">
<option>-</option>
<option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
<option value="arial">Arial</option>
</select>

<br />Font Weight:
<select id="fontweight">
<option>-</option>
<option value="bold">Bold</option>
<option value="regular">Regular</option>
</select>

<div>
<textarea id="label" class='address'>Hello 123</textarea>
<textarea class='address'>Hello 123</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be shortened to single function by adjusting `html` , `js` ; setting `id` of element to property to be set at `css` ; substituting `normal` for `regular` at `fontFamily` element ; using `RegExp.prototype.test()` to check for digit in value of element to return length value including `"px"` or string of `select` value when setting `css` value.

html

```
Font Size:
<select name="fontSize" id="fontSize">
    <option>-</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
</select>
<br />Font Type:
<select name="fontFamily" id="fontFamily">
    <option>-</option>
    <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
</select>
<br />Font Weight:
<select name="fontWeight" id="fontWeight">
    <option>-</option>
    <option value="bold">Bold</option>
    <option value="normal">Normal</option>
</select>
<div>
<textarea id="label" class='address'>Hello 123</textarea>
<textarea class='address'>Hello 123</textarea>
</div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $("[id^=font]").on("change", function () {
       $(".address")
       .css(this.id, /\d/.test(this.value) ? this.value + "px" : this.value);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/73udajhm/6/

Comment: should not remove the name property, it might be needed in postback later on. Better to add id together with name

Comment: @guest271314 In a single function, only font-size should have a 'px' suffix.

Answer (score 2):

Just check your coding.

The family doesn't work because you set `name` instead of `id` on the font type selector.

And `regular` should be `normal` for `font-weight`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the cleanest version:

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function() {
    var $property = $(this).attr('name');
    var $value = $(this).data("sufix") ? $(this).val() + $(this).data("sufix") : $(this).val();
    $('.address').css($property, $value);
  });

});
```

```html
Font Size:
<select name="font-size" data-sufix="px">
  <option>-</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
</select>
<br />Font Type:
<select name="font-family">
  <option>-</option>
  <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
</select>
<br />Font Weight:
<select name="font-weight">
  <option>-</option>
  <option value="bold">Bold</option>
  <option value="normal">Normal</option>
</select>
<div>
  <textarea id="label" class='address'>Hello 123</textarea>
  <textarea class='address'>Hello 123</textarea>
</div>
```

Cheers!